# Cannot edit CiviCase Activity Status from list view

Tags: civicase, activity, status

From the List view of CiviCase Activities of a case, I cannot edit the "Status" of an activity; the drop down flashes and then goes back to current status. To edit, I have to click "edit" and go into every single Activity one by one. Is this a bug or a set-up problem?

Comment: Could be a both ;-) What you could do is use chrome/firefox and press f12 this will open a developer tool which might show some errors. Those errors could probably give an indication fo what goes wrong.

Comment: Note that you need to click on `tick` button in order to save your selection in the dropdown.

Comment: This has now been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

As a clue to lead to possible answer, I am seeing the same kind of issue when I try to edit an activity. Drop-down boxes (e.g., status) and search-for-match fields (e.g.,assignees) are hidden behind the activity screen and, even if the screen is minimized, do not allow editing when clicked. We are WordPress 4.97, CiviCRM 5.3.2. This is the first we've encountered this.